# Stop cron script from destroying my mirrorlist with invalid data

Tags: bash, arch-linux, cron

I have to following **cron** script that runs daily. As you should be able to see from the code, it outputs the results from `reflector` to `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist`.

```
$ cat /etc/cron.daily/update-mirrorlist
#!/bin/bash

reflector -l 5 -r -o /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
```

Sometimes, `reflector` outputs a empty file and thus a invalid *mirrorlist* is created.

How can I modify the script above to only write to `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist` **IF** there is valid output from `relfector`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a good idea to first accumulate the data, then move it into place. That way the target file will always be valid, even while the data accumulator program is running.

```
set -e
target=/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
reflector -l 5 -r -o "$target.tmp"
mv -f -- "$target.tmp" "$target"
```

If `reflector` does not properly report errors by returning a nonzero status, add your own validation test before the `mv` command, for example `test -s "$target.tmp"` to test that the file is not empty.

If you want to keep a backup of the old version, add `ln -f -- "$target" "$target.old" || true` before the `mv` command.

Comment: what does `set -e` do?

Comment: @Stefan: `set -e` tells the shell to stop the script as soon as a command returns a nonzero status (conventionally indicating a failure). (If a command is allowed to fail, such as `ln` in my answer, adding `|| true` after it ensures that that command as a whole always succeeds and won't terminate the script.)